# Recursion prove by induction

Tags: induction

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
f(n-1) + n(n-1) & \text{if $n>0$ }\\
0 & \text{if $n=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Prove by induction that for all $n$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$

$$
f(n) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2 - \sum\limits_{i=0}^n i
$$

Base Case: When $n=0$ $f(0) = 0$ and when $n=1$ $f(1) = 0$

Any hints on this? I am not sure how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base case is good. Suppose by induction that for some fixed $k-1 \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $$f(k-1)=\sum^{k-1}_{i=0} i^2-\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}i.$$
Then, by definition $$f(k)= f(k-1)+k(k-1)=(\sum^{k-1}_{i=0} i^2-\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}i) + k(k-1).$$

But, $k(k-1) = k^2-k = (\sum^{k}_{i=0} i^2-\sum^{k}_{i=0}i) -(\sum^{k-1}_{i=0} i^2-\sum^{k-1}_{i=0}i).$

Comment: Does it mean your Induction Hypothesis is $n=k-1$ and to prove is $k$?

Comment: Correct. I suppose to holds for an *arbitrary fixe*d $k-1 \in \mathbb{N}.$ Then, I show it is true for $k$.

Answer (score 0):

induction hypothesis let for $n=k$
$$f(k)=\sum_{i=0}^ki^2-\sum_{i=0}^ki$$
Prove for $n=k+1$: we have
$$f(k+1)=f(k)+k(k+1)$$ by induction hypothesis:
$$f(k)=\sum_{i=0}^ki^2-\sum_{i=0}^ki,$$
so
$$f(k+1)=\sum_{i=0}^ki^2-\sum_{i=0}^ki+k(k+1)\color{red}{\pm(k+1)}=\sum_{i=0}^ki^2-\sum_{i=0}^ki+(k+1)^2-(k+1)$$